# Is modification allowed if license does not mention it?

Tags: licensing, legal, copyright

I recently came across this license agreement on software:

> Personal Use License
>
> The content owner grants the buyer a non-exclusive, perpetual, personal use
>   license to view, download, display, and copy the content, subject to the
>   following restrictions:
>
> The content is licensed for personal use only, not commercial use. The
>   content may not be used in any way whatsoever in which you charge money,
>   collect fees, or receive any form of remuneration. The content may not be
>   resold, relicensed, sub-licensed, rented, leased, or used in advertising.
>
> Title and ownership, and all rights now and in the future, of and for the
>   content remain exclusively with the content owner.
>
> There are no warranties, express or implied. The content is provided 'as
>   is.'
>
> Neither the content owner, payment processing service, nor hosting service
>   will be liable for any third party claims or incidental, consequential, or
>   other damages arising out of this license or the buyer's use of the content.

The first sentence contains the following:

> license to view, download, display, and copy the content

It does not mention anything about modifications. Is modification legal in this case? Does it violate the license if a modified version is distributed with the same license?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifying a copyrighted work is creating a [derivative work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work). This must be granted by the copyright holder (see [here](https://www.legalzoom.com/articles/what-are-derivative-works-under-copyright-law)), which seems not to be the case in the license that you quote.

But attention:  copyright law is a complex matter.  Moreover it's not universal, but country dependent.  So if your question is business related, you'd better consult a lawyer or a qualified legal advisor in your jurisdiction.